# Substr to exclude certain text - using a list of get_the_title()

Tags: php, wordpress, substr

Lets say I have a list of titles in wordpress eg. **Item Name - (USA)**

I would like to return just **Item Name** so everything after the `-` is not returned.

One catch is not all of the titles in my list have a `-` and the ones that don't return a blank when I use the code below:

```
$str = get_the_title();
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-'));
echo $str;
```

Any idea how I get it to not return blanks on titles that don't have a hyphen `-` ?

Comment: [`strtok()`](http://php.net/strtok) is often a better substitute.

Answer (score 0):

### Regular expressions way

Use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and then just [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the result.

```
$string = 'Item Name - (USA)';
var_dump(trim(preg_replace('~-.*$~', null, $string)));
```

**Returns:**

```
string(9) "Item Name"
```

**Explanation:**

1. `preg_replace('~-.*$~', null, $string)` Catch all characters from the first `-` to the end of the string and replace those with `null`.
2. `trim($string)` And remove whitespace characters from both sides of the string.

### Non-Regular expresions way

Use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to divide the string and get the first member from the resulting array and then [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) it.

```
$string = 'Item Name - (USA)';
var_dump(trim(reset(explode("-", $string))));
```

**Returns:**

```
string(9) "Item Name"
```

Comment: My problem is some of the strings in my list (generated from get_the_title() function in wordpress) don't have `-` hyphens and in those cases my code returns blank. In the cases where hyphens are present my code works fine.

Comment: I know. My code works fine **with** *and* **without** hyphens in strings :)

Comment: I appreciate your help but I cannot get it to work with get_the_title() `$str = get_the_title();
$str = (trim(reset(explode("-", $str))));
echo $str;`

Comment: Well, **it does work *with hyphens***: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/307507f49bfcb5a04ac3ee74acac424621adbf2e
You may want to check if wordpress really gives you hyphens and not some other character instead.